# Change the location of a dynamically created Drop Down List in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I made a Drop down list with 7 options. When I choose any of the 7 options, a new Drop down list is created. My problem is I don't know how to change the location of the dynamically created drop down list.
Here's my code for new drop down list:

```
function displayAccordingly() {
      var field1 = document.getElementById('field1');
      var whereToPut = document.getElementById('myDiv');
      var newDropdown = document.createElement('select');
      newDropdown.setAttribute('id',"newField")
      whereToPut.appendChild(newDropdown);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by wheretoput? Some kind of html might help, like are you trying to append it to a div or some other element?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have much knowledge of javascript or a html and i found a tutorial online. Yes this is in my html code <div id="myDiv"></div>

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys.It seems that when i change the location of "<div id="myDiv"></div>" it also changes the location of the new drop down list.
Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

I think the location is defined by the variable `whereToPut` - try to change it and see the result.

For example: `whereToPut=document.body;`